# Custom Svelte widget error "_bind is not a function"

Tags: svelte

I've a very simple contenteditable Svelte widget width double bindings to the innerHtmL:

```
<div ref:editor contenteditable on:input="textChanged(e)">
  {{{html}}}
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            html: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        textChanged() {
            this.set({
              html: this.refs.editor.innerHTML
            });
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

I can reference to it as:

```
<Editor bind:html />
```

But in the console there is an odd error:

```
editor._bind is not a function
```

It seems to work, but the error is there. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using svelte-loader with `hotReload: true` by any chance? I just ran into the same thing, it's possible that's where the bug lies

Comment: are you trying to access html from parent? why not use events?